# Acessar propriedades de um arquivo em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu quero acessar as propriedades de um arquivo utilizando Python. Vi que é possível fazer isso usando a função `listxattr` do módulo OS, porém ao tentar utilizar, ele me gera um erro. Veja meu código abaixo:

```
import os
print(os.listxattr('teste.txt'))
```

> AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'listxattr'

Quero fazer um sistema de upload de arquivos. Minha ideia é marcar os arquivos enviados com alguma informação, evitando fazer o upload novamente e o cliente precisa dos arquivos na maquina local.

Estou em ambiente Windows. O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

O que eu quero fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que tipo de informação você precisa? Algo como => https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result

Comment: A função `os.listxattr()` está assinalada como exclusiva para Linux: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#linux-extended-attributes

Comment: @Diogo mudei a pergunta. Conseguiu entender?

Comment: @AugustoVasques E como eu faria o mesmo com o Windows?

Comment: A mesma resposta que o Diogo deu [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) ou então algo mais próximo do OS como `win32api.GetFileAttributes()`

Comment: como está na minha resposta: não há a opção de se anexar metadados arbitrários a um arquivo, - Até é possível  "esconder" informação a mais no filesystem que você consiga achar com seu próprio progama - mas a interface gráfica do Windows não vai mostrar essa informação

Comment: Exemplo de como "codificar a informação lá: você poderia convencionar que se a timestamp de alteração de um arquivo terminar em um segundo par, ele foi enviado, se terminar num segundo impar, ele não foi enviado. É possível mudar essa timestamp - mas extrair essa informação e mostrar na janela nativa do windows não dá - a pessoa teria que usar um programa seu para ver as informaçoes extras sobre o arquivo. E aí, é mais fácil simplesmente manter as informações em um arquivo paralelo  - sem precisar de hacks.

Comment: O que me deixa chateado é que no linux é super fácil de fazer, mas no windows aparentemente não há como

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `.stat` de objetos `pathlib.Path` traz as informações na forma de uma NamedTuple (basicamente, trás os atributos):

```py
In [1]: from pathlib import Path                                                                                                     

In [2]: Path("teste.txt").stat()                                                                                                     
Out[2]: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5512541, st_dev=64770, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1301285014, st_gid=1301283329, st_size=0, st_atime=1580502110, st_mtime=1580502110, st_ctime=1580502110)

In [6]: info = Path("teste.txt").stat()                                                                                              

In [7]: from datetime import datetime                                                                                                

In [8]: datetime.fromtimestamp(info.st_atime)                                                                                        
Out[8]: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 31, 17, 21, 50, 59767)
```

Em versões anteriores ao Python 3.5, o m´odulo pathlib não existia, e é possível se obter a mesma resposta chamando-se a função `stat` no módulo `os` passando o arquivo como uma string:

```py
In [10]: os.stat("teste.txt")                                                                                                        
Out[10]: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5512541, st_dev=64770, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1301285014, st_gid=1301283329, st_size=0, st_atime=1580502110, st_mtime=1580502110, st_ctime=1580502110)
```

A vantagem de usar o `pathlib.Path` é que o Python já sabe que não é só uma string: é um caminho para um arquivo, e o próprio objeto tem vários métodos, como `open`, `read_text`, `rename`, simplificando muito qualquer trabalho que vá ser feito com arquivos.

Mas o `stat` só lè as informações do arquivo,disponíveis no sistema de arquivos, ele não serve para marcar qualquer uma dessas propriedades.  Você pode ou fazer suas marcações no próprio nome dos arquivos, ou manter um arquivo em paralelo, no mesmo diretório, em que você serializa um dicionário Python com todas as informações que desejar sobre os outros arquivos no diretório.

**atualização**
A pergunta foi editada depois de eu responder e as intenções do AP ficaram mais claras - eu comentei na pergunta explicando melhor algumas coisas depois dessa edição - estou atualizando a resposta para incluir o conteúdo dos comentários:

**Não há una forma**, independente de sistema opracional, de se anexar metadados arbitrários a um arquivo. A existência dessas meta-informações depende não só do sistema operacional, mas do sistema de arquivos. - Até é possível "esconder" informação a mais no filesystem que você consiga achar com seu próprio programa - mas a interface gráfica do Windows não vai mostrar essa informação.

Exemplo de como "codificar a informação lá: você poderia convencionar que se a timestamp de alteração de um arquivo terminar em um segundo par, ele foi enviado, se terminar num segundo impar, ele não foi enviado. É possível mudar essa timestamp - mas extrair essa informação e mostrar na janela nativa do windows não dá - a pessoa teria que usar um programa seu para ver as informaçoes extras sobre o arquivo. E aí, é mais fácil simplesmente manter as informações em um arquivo paralelo - sem precisar de hacks. –

Como colocado na pergunta - no Linux, pelo menos nos sistemas de arquivos mais comuns, isso é possível sim, e as funcionalidades estão disponíveis no Python nas funções `os.setxattr`, `os.listxattr`, `os.getxattr` e `os.removexattr` documentadas aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#linux-extended-attributes